# Can I build a Colecovision AC adapter from multiple other adapters?

Tags: hardware

Can I use multiple small AC adaptors to make a working Colecovision AC adaptor? For example, two 5V, one 12V and the ground. Colecovision AC adaptors are too expensive.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Please read the [tour]; be aware that Stack Exchange is different to most forums.

Comment: Welcome. Here's an entertaining video to show you one simple approach to similar problem with the C64: https://youtu.be/UCdXV0X6wEY

Comment: You just need a 12 VDC solution, vice 9VAC...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as long as:

1. You use power supplies that can deliver the amount of current the ColecoVision needs.
2. The 5V power supply grounds are 'floating', i.e. not connected to ground or neutral from the power cord (this is required so that you can hook up one of the 5V supplies backwards to get -5V from it).
3. You have sufficient electric/electronic knowledge and experience to do this without creating a safety/fire hazard and/or injuring yourself.

Comment: can I get a diagram please

Comment: can I use just one 5v power supply for both the +5v and the -5v.

Comment: If you can meet requirement #3 you shouldn't need a diagram.  You just need to tie the ground of one 5V supply to the ground of the 12V supply, then tie both of those to the +5V of your second 5V supply (at which point ground on the second 5V supply becomes -5V).  You can't use one 5V supply for both +5V and -5V because you would effectively short-circuit the power supply that way.

Comment: https://ibb.co/xgcPgqL is that a what you meant

Comment: Yes, assuming the pins going from left to right are ground, +12V, -5V, +5V.